# Blank values stored in database - Ajax Forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am building forms using AJAX and encountering a problem:

Whenever I submit the form, the values stored in the database go blank ... (FYI, of course the page doesn't refresh.. that's the whole point.)

[image: Blank Values]

Here is my file *index.php*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myForm">
        Name: <input name="username" type="radio" value="Sagar">Sagar</input>
              <input name="username" type="radio" value="Saransh">Saransh</input><br /><br />
        Profession: <input name="profession" type="radio" value="Coder">Coder</input>
                    <input name="profession" type="radio" value="Entrepreneur">Entrepreneur</input>
                    <input name="profession" type="radio" value="Blogger">Blogger</input><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "data.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data:{
            "username":$('input[name=username]:checked', '#myForm').val(),
            "profession": $('input[name=profession]:checked', '#myForm').val()
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my *Data.php*:

```
<?php 

require 'connect.php';

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('cant use'. DB_NAME . ':'. mysql_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$profession = $_POST['profession'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO info (Name, Profession) VALUES('{$username}', '{$profession}')");

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Some Error '. mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you echo out the userame and profession to make sure the data was sent through the ajax post?

Comment: The page doesn't even refresh.. so there's no point in echoing out the username in data.php. And if you are asking for echoing it out in index.php itself then the variable doesn't even exist as we have not yet submitted the form. So , either way its not going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                url: 'data.php',
                data:{
                    "username":$('input[name=username]:checked', '#myForm').val(),
                    "profession": $('input[name=profession]:checked', '#myForm').val()
                },
                success: function(response)
                {       

                }
            }).error(function(request, status, error){
                 console.log(e);
            });
     });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit with this

```
 <script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').on('click', function(){
               var username=$('input[name="username"]:checked').val();
               var profession=$('input[name="profession"]:checked').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'data.php',
                    data:"username=" + username+ "&profession="+ profession, 
                    success: function(response)
                    {       

                    }
                }).error(function(request, status, error){
                     console.log(e);
                });
         });

        });
    </script>
```